# Xcode Cloud Error: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, xcode-cloud

When XCode Cloud is building my app, this error appears:

```
/Downloads/friendship.json: No such file or directory
```

My Copy Bundle Resources the file is located in downloads, and I put it in a group in Xcode. Is there a way to remove the downloads section and put it in Xcode directly?

The build is working fine when I remove the Copy Bundle Resources.